# Cordova - Why does app page navigation work locally but fails after deploying via TestFlight on iPhone?

Tags: cordova, navigation, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

Encountering a challenge with page navigation in a Cordova app, I employ the following code for transitioning from one page to another:

`window.location.href= 'demo.html'`

During local testing on my iPhone through the build process, the navigation functions seamlessly. However, when deploying the app via a TestFlight testing link, issues arise as the navigation buttons cease to operate effectively.

I've ensured that the code is correct, as it works in one context but not in another. Any help in identifying potential causes or solutions for this navigation problem when using Cordova with TestFlight would be greatly appreciated.

when attempting to navigate between pages in a Cordova app using the `window.location.href` code, the navigation functions correctly during local testing on an iPhone through the local build process. However, when deploying the app via TestFlight and accessing it through a testing link, the navigation buttons stop working.

I am likely seeking insights into the reasons behind this inconsistency and am interested in understanding potential solutions or workarounds to ensure consistent page navigation in both testing environments.